# How to submit a python SnappyData job

Tags: apache-spark, snappydata

SnappyData documentation (docs/programming_guide/using_the_spark_shell_and_spark-submit.md)
show that it's possible to submit a python program to Spark (master default port 7077) that can make use of SnappyData tables:

> $ ./bin/spark-submit --class
>   io.snappydata.examples.AirlineDataSparkApp --master
>   spark://masterhost:7077 --conf
>   spark.snappydata.connection=locatorhost:clientPort
>   $SNAPPY_HOME/examples/jars/quickstart.jar

My question: Spark port 7077 doesn't seem to be listening.  Does it have to be configured manually?

(Assumption: I assume that port 7077 belongs to the Spark that comes with SnappyData, and not a separate Spark cluster.)

Comment: You will need to launch a spark standalone cluster using <snappyData_home>/sbin/start-all.sh ... this will launch the spark master on port 7077.

Comment: So, do you need a 2nd Spark cluster just to submit a parallel python job (that uses SnappyData tables)?
Or is there a way to launch a python snappy job that uses SnappyData's spark nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Snappy data server JVMs cannot run Python "inside". But, you can use the same nodes to launch a Spark master and workers - these are very light weight. Run the workers collocated with the nodes you use to run SnappyData "data servers". 
Note that whether a Job (e.g. Java, scala) runs within the data servers or not they need similar resources (CPU, memory).